# Invalid module name odoo 10

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I've install odoo on a ubuntu VM and on a server to start developing module but I can't install my module on my odoo, I have this error:

> jourconge odoo.modules.loading: invalid module names, ignored:
>   hr_hollidays_fr

I launch my odoo with this command

```
./odoo-bin -d jourconge --addons-path=/home/odoo/odoo/addons,/home/odoo/enterprise,/home/odoo/technical-training/09-orm --db-filter=jourconge -i hr_hollidays_fr
```

I use as module name my folder name .

Addons-path are good one, I've tried to install odoo's module located in odoo/addons and it worked.

To create my module I've created the folder "fraisperso", I add the file __manifest__.py and __init__.py.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

{

```
'name': "Public Holidays FR",



'summary': """

    Gestion des week end et jours fériés""",



'description': """

    Module qui permet la gestion des jours fériés et des week-end dans le compte des jours de congés pour une demande de congés

""",



'author': "Martin Allimonier",



# Categories can be used to filter modules in modules listing

# Check https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/master/odoo/addons/base/module/module_data.xml

# for the full list

'category': 'hr',

'version': '0.1',



# any module necessary for this one to work correctly

'depends': ['base', 'hr_holidays'],



# always loaded

'data': [

    # 'security/ir.model.access.csv',



],
```

}

My __init__.py just import the models folder where I ve created my model and a folder views where I've put my views.

My question is what did I miss?

Thanks for helping and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Please don't add links to code screenshots - this is unhandy. Please edit your question and include all relevant code as text with the right formatting.

Comment: Fixed code, grammar, spelling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, did you not use the 'scaffold' to create that module?
Anyway, each module have two names, the technical one and the display one.
The technical one, which is the same to use with the 'i'/'u' parameter, is the folder name.
So you should replace 'hr_hollidays_fr' with 'fraisperso' or whatever you called the directory, or change your folder name to 'hr_hollidays_fr'.

Comment: And just as remainder, to create modules use the 'scaffold' command.

Comment: thank you for your help, i ve use scaffold and it work